# Choose between Enabled and Disables option from dropdown in selenium webdrivers

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am New to Web-drivers
I want to choose an option between enabled and disabled option from dropdown menu..
For Example..having 2 option as

1. [image: Here i cannot click on **check-out-and-edit** as **undo-checkout is visible**]
   2.[image: If this condition i continue with my code]

So the scenario is..
I cannot click on **check-out-and-edit** option if **undo-checkout** is visible..
So i want the code sample for this condition such that..
If my **undo-checkout** is visible then i click on **undo-check** and then on **check-out-Edit** option butttttt if my **check-out-and-edit** is all ready visible then i should continue with my code..

My Sample code..

```
boolean c1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Undo Checkout")).isEnabled();
if(c1== true){

}
else{

}
```

But Boolean returning me only true value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get id for undo-checkout using below code..

```
String e =driver.findElement(By.linkText("Undo Checkout")).getAttribute("id");
```

once you get it then put condition in try and catch block
as...

```
       try {
            WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("//id of undo-checkout"));
            undocheckout();
            }catch (Exception e) {
            WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.id("//id of checkout-and-edit""));
            checkoutandedit();
            }
```

if 1st is present try will execute otherwise catch will execute...

Answer (score 1):

```
I am assuming that u have something like below html code written for option u have give:



        <option value="0" ></option>
        <option value="1" >check-out-and-edit</option>
        <option value="2" disabled>undo-checkout</option>




The  first try to fetch the list of options you have, then for each option in the list try to find the one having disable as attribute associated with it.
For your reference I have given some sample code below.
Hope this help.

`List<WebElement> opts = temp.findElements(By.xpath(".//option"));
WebElement dis_elem;
for (WebElement opt : opts){ 
if(dis_elem = opt.getAttribute("disabled")!= null)
{
    if(dis_elem.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("check-out-and-edit")
    {
        //Put the logic u want to execute in case undo-checkout option is eanble.
    }
    Else if if(dis_elem.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("undo-checkout")
    {
        //  Put the logic u want to execute in case check-out-and-edit option is eanble.
    }
}
}`

Else please post the HTML code of your page.
```